# A question about "welfare independence"

Tags: economics

I am working on some applications of measures of inequality (economic inequality). Upon reading a paper by Kolm (Kolm, S. C., Unequal Inequalities I, Journal of Economic Theory, 12 pp 416-442, 1976) I found a result that I found intriguing and for which I would like to know if any one has a reference or a proof of.

The author introduces an axiomatization of measures of economic inequality. These are functions $I:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow[0,\infty)$, satisfying  some ideal properties such as "Impartiality" ($I$ is invariant under permutations);  transfer principle ($\partial_iI-(x_i-x_j)\partial_jI\geq0$), and others.

The following properties are the ones which are rather intriguing to me. Let $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]^\intercal\in U$ and denote  $\bar{\mathbf{x}}=\frac1n\sum^n_{j=1}x_j$, define
\begin{align}
\hat{x}(\mathbf{x})&=\bar{\mathbf{x}}-I(\mathbf{x})\\
\tilde{x}(\mathbf{x})&=(1-I(\mathbf{x}))\bar{\mathbf{x}}
\end{align}
The author calls this quantities *welfare indices*. The following properties in considered in the axiomatization:

(1) (absolute) For all $1\leq i,j\leq n$, the ratio $\frac{\partial_i\hat{x}}{\partial_j\hat{x}}$ depends only on $x_i$ and $x_j$, that is
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial_i\hat{x}}{\partial_j\hat{x}}=\psi_{ij}(x_i,x_j)\tag{1}\label{one}\end{align}$$
for some function $\psi_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

(1') (relative) For all $1\leq i,j\leq n$, the ratio $\frac{\partial_i\tilde{x}}{\partial_j\tilde{x}}$ depends only on $x_i$ and $x_j$, that is
$$\begin{align}\frac{\partial_i\tilde{x}}{\partial_j\tilde{x}}=\phi_{ij}(x_i,x_j)\tag{1'}\label{onep}\end{align}$$
for some function $\phi_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

(1) and (1'), the author argues, may be called (or labeled) ***welfare independence***.
There are no additional properties on $I$ except that presumably is smooth (as differentiable as one needs it). Under this general assumptions, he says
that

> Well-known results in economics show that (1) or (1') is equivalent to saying that there exists a function of this social index which can be written as a sum of funcyions of each of the $x_j$'s.

Mathematically, this is expressed by the author as saying that there is a (smooth) function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and (smooth) $V_j:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ ($j=1,\ldots,n$) such that
$$\begin{align}
\hat{x}(\mathbf{x})= F\big(\sum^n_{j=1}V_j(x_j)\big)\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}$$
(similarly for $\tilde{x}$).

---

**The mathematical problem:** It is clear that if a function $\hat{x}$ is of the form \eqref{two}, then the ratios $\frac{\partial_i\hat{x}}{\partial_j\hat{x}}=\frac{V'_i(x_i)}{V'(x_j)}$ depend on $\mathbf{x}$ only through $x_i$ and $x_j$. It is the converse part is what it is not clear to me, that is,

> If $\hat{x}:U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function which satisfies property \eqref{one}, then $\hat{x}$ must be of the form \eqref{two} ($n\geq3$).

Any reference, or additional assumptions pertaining to some other conditions that welfare indices must satisfy, will be appreciated.